# nifi fetching attribute from json file

Tags: apache-nifi

I need to fetch the second attribute from a json file. and have tried to use 'evaluateJsonPath' processor and/or 'attributetoJson' processor, in both of which case i always get the whole line instead of single attribute.

in the json processor I added the property as 'bouncers_mobile_social' and value as '$.bouncers_mobile_social' yet getting the full line.

the sample json is
{"mtimespent_other": 0.4, "bouncers_mobile_social": 45, "numvisitors_mobile_search": 647}

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

I created [a template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/ade5f82ce2d0c1394326e4bcb2dc5de5) demonstrating that a `GenerateFlowFile` processor which creates the JSON you provided and is passed to an `EvaluateJSONPath` processor with the property you provided works. Please check the configuration, typos, unexpected input data, etc.

[image: NiFi flow demonstrating success]
[image]